# Not able to handle popup window that is showing immediately after login

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After login my main window disabled and one popup window showing. I tried to switch window, directly clicking cancel element on alert but none of them working.

I attached image with html code and popup window for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code too

Answer (score 0):

As per screenshot, cssSelector having 2 matching nodes, so have a look for specific Cancel element. It may pointing to wrong element.

If you have correct locator then try with

waits, if not works Thread.sleep helps sometime to simulate click properly,

As HTMLcode is not clear, check if Cancel element is inside iframe/frame or not,if it is inside a iframe/frame then switch to frame,

As we are seeing HTML code, so it is not Alert, check in HTML instead of Firepath to see if it is new windows or try getWinddowHandles, get size of set, to see as it is window or not

```
 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles() ;
```

We can try, switch to active element also

If webdriver click is working, you can try click by using javascriptexecutor

```
 WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//elementpath"));

 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```